# W and Z boson masses' running neglected?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, renormalization

Since the Lagrangian mass term of $W$ boson involves the bare coupling $g$, it cannot be the measured mass. Then the measured mass will "run" with momentum transferred. But everywhere I look the "running" of $m_W$ is omitted, and the specific value is given without mentioning at what energies it is measured. My question is - does the mass $m_W$ change noticeably up to unification scales (~$10^{16}$ GeV)? And what people take as the "default" $m_W$ measurement scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We never measure Lagrangian mass. We measure pole mass - the real part of the denominator of a propagator. Pole mass, by construction of the renormalization group, is independent of energy or renormalization scales. It does not run.

Occasionally, we extract renormalized mass from measurements, i.e. in a particular scheme and at a particular scale, extract the renormalized mass (but this depends on the scheme, i.e. the choice of finite pieces in the renormalized and counter-term masses).

Comment: Can the renormalized mass be equal to the pole mass at some energy?

Comment: Hmm. If there is an energy at which all couplings vanish, then yes, at that energy they'd be no corrections so physical would be renormalized. If you make a judicuous choice, eg pick $\mu=m_\text{physical}$, you might minimise loop corrections, but I don't think they'll vanish in general.